# What about a mutable struct that's immutable from the standpoint of external code?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, immutability, mutable

**Update**: It occurred to me after posting this question that the main downside of this idea would simply be that such a type would be easy to use improperly. That is, the type would have to be used in a very specific way to draw any benefits. What I originally had in mind was something that would be used like this (sticking with the `SquareRootStruct` example from the original question just for consistency):

```
class SomeClass
{
    SquareRootStruct _key;

    public SomeClass(int value)
    {
        _key = new SquareRootStruct(value);
    }

    public double SquareRoot
    {
        // External code would have to access THIS property for caching
        // to provide any benefit.
        get { return _key.SquareRoot; }
    }

    public SquareRootStruct GetCopyOfKey()
    {
        // If _key has cached its calculation, then its copy will carry
        // the cached results with it.
        return _key;
    }
}

// elsewhere in the code...
var myObject = new SomeClass();

// If I do THIS, only a COPY of myObject's struct is caching a calculation,
// which buys me nothing.
double x = myObject.GetCopyOfKey().SquareRoot;

// So I would need to do this in order to get the benefit (which is,
// admittedly, confusing)...
double y = myObject.SquareRoot;
```

So, considering how easy this would be to get wrong, I'm inclined to think that maybe Reed's right (in his comment) that this would make more sense as a class.

---

Suppose I have a `struct` that I want to have the following characteristics:

1. Immutable from an *external* vantage point
2. Fast to initialize
3. Lazy calculation (and caching) of certain properties

Obviously the third characteristic implies *mutability*, which we all know is bad (assuming the mantra "Don't make mutable value types!" has been drilled into our heads sufficiently). But it seems to me that this would be acceptable as long as the mutable part is visible only internally to the type itself, and from outside code's perspective the value would always be the same.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
struct SquareRootStruct : IEquatable<SquareRootStruct>
{
    readonly int m_value;  // This will never change.

    double m_sqrt;         // This will be calculated on the first property
                           // access, and thereafter never change (so it will
                           // appear immutable to external code).

    bool m_sqrtCalculated; // This flag will never be visible
                           // to external code.

    public SquareRootStruct(int value) : this()
    {
        m_value = value;
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get { return m_value; }
    }

    public double SquareRoot
    {
        if (!m_sqrtCalculated)
        {
            m_sqrt = Math.Sqrt((double)m_value);
            m_sqrtCalculated = true;
        }

        return m_sqrt;
    }

    public bool Equals(SquareRootStruct other)
    {
        return m_value == other.m_value;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is SquareRootStruct && Equals((SquareRootStruct)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return m_value;
    }
}
```

Now, obviously this is a **trivial example**, as `Math.Sqrt` is almost certainly not costly enough to consider this approach worthwhile in this case. It's only an example for illustration purposes.

But my thinking is that this accomplishes my three objectives where the most obvious alternative approaches would not. Specifically:

- I *could* perform the calculation in the type's constructor; but this would potentially fall short of the 2nd objective above (fast to initialize).
- I *could* perform the calculation on every property access; but this would potentially fall short of the 3rd objective above (caching of calculated result for future accesses).

So yes, this idea would effectively lead to a value type that is internally mutable. However, as far as any external code could tell (as I see it), it would *appear* immutable, while bringing with it some performance benefits (again, I realize the above example would *not* be an appropriate use of this idea; the "performance benefits" I'm talking about would be contingent on the calculation actually being sufficiently costly to warrant caching).

Am I missing something, or is this in fact a worthwhile idea?

Comment: I've done that sort of thing from time to time.  Seems reasonable to me.  I assume you'd have to be some sort of FP purist to take umbrage.

Comment: @Kirk: True - but then the question becomes, "Why do you want this to be a struct" vs. a class?  If your really doing "work" to compute values, is it really a candidate for a struct in the first place?

Comment: @Reed Copsey: Isn't the question struct vs. class rather a question whether the type should have value type semantics and not whether you need to do any internal calculations? Think about the `DateTime` struct which e.g. computes the `Year` or `Day` properties on the fly.

Comment: @0xA3: If it’s externally immutable, then it makes no difference whether it’s a reference or value type. The only difference between reference semantics and value semantics is that mutating a field of a value type is guaranteed to have no effect on any other variable of that type.

Comment: @OxA3: I'd argue that's not a good comparison.  DateTime just provides those properties as helpers - just like any other method that does value type conversion.  In that situation, it's not doing anything to its own internal state in order to make it work.  Mutable structs tend to have odd side effects, and as soon as you really start needing to mutate them (even if it's for laziness), I question whether they should be classes instead.

Comment: @Dan Tao: BTW - You might want to look at using Lazy<T> inside of a class for this type of operation - it gives you thread safety and a very easy, clean API.

Comment: Any time structs are mutated by methods, rather than via constructors or direct field assignment, strange semantics will result in many situation which return structs by value.  It's too bad there's no "mutator" keyword which could be applied to a method to indicate that (1) the method cannot be used on a read-only struct, and (2) if used on a read/write property, the struct must be written back after the method is called.  That would avoid a lot of confusion.

Comment: @supercat: Agreed. Probably way too specific a feature for the C# team to ever consider seriously, though, I'd wager.

Comment: @Dan Tao: I wouldn't consider it over-specific.  To be sure, read-modify-write on structures would likely be somewhat inefficient, but a "mutator" keyword would ensure that code which compiles would have proper semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with having immutable data structures that internally use mutation (so long as the thread safety is well advertised). It's just that structs get copied all the time, so you can't do much with mutation. This isn't a problem in C/C++ because structs are usually passed by reference, whereas in C# it is rare to pass structs by reference. Since it's hard to reason about structs that are passed by value, mutable structs are discouraged in C#.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the kicker -- .NET developers just aren't used to passing structs by reference, so this idea would easily be abused, I think. I had a similar revelation (to myself) shortly before you posted this.

Comment: Can you think of a mutable struct C standard library that gets passed by value?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe could probably work somewhat, but with an important caveat: the result of the slow calculation may or may not get stored when it is computed.  For example, if the calculation is performed on the structs returned by an enumeration, the results will get stored in 'temporary' structs and will be discarded rather than propagated back into the ones stored in the data structure.

Comment: Good call -- as you can see from my update, this problem occurred to me after posting (and Gabe pointed out basically the same problem). It seems like it *could* work, but it would require very careful and deliberate usage to make it worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

This looks similar to a [Future](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_%28programming%29). There was some mention of better support for Futures in C# 4.0 parallel extensions. (Like computing them on another core/thread in parallel to your normal work).

Comment: I'm honestly struggling to understand how this relates to immutability.

Comment: @Kirk Woll: It was my interpretation of the question that this was more about delaying computation than immutability.

Comment: And OK, perhaps the Wikipedia page is a bit broad, but in the first paragraph it states: "[Futures] describe an object that acts as a proxy for a result that is initially not known, usually because the computation of its value has not yet completed."